# How to fix "Example could not be unloaded" error when writing a BetterDiscord plugin?

Tags: discord

So I found a example plugin script:

```
//META{"name":"Example"}*//

class Example {
    // Constructor
    constructor() {
        this.initialized = false;
    }

    // Meta
    getName() { return "Example"; }
    getShortName() { return "Example"; }
    getDescription() { return "This is an example/template for a BD plugin."; }
    getVersion() { return "0.1.0"; }
    getAuthor() { return "Minin"; }

    // Settings  Panel
    getSettingsPanel() {
        return "<!--Enter Settings Panel Options, just standard HTML-->";
    }
    
    // Load/Unload
    load() { }

    unload() { }

    // Events

    onMessage() {
        PluginUtilities.showToast("New message!")
    };

    onSwitch() {
        // Called when a server or channel is switched
    };

    observer(e) {
        // raw MutationObserver event for each mutation
    };
    
    // Start/Stop
    start() {
        var libraryScript = document.getElementById('zeresLibraryScript');
    if (!libraryScript) {
        libraryScript = document.createElement("script");
        libraryScript.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
        libraryScript.setAttribute("src", "https://rauenzi.github.io/BetterDiscordAddons/Plugins/PluginLibrary.js");
        libraryScript.setAttribute("id", "zeresLibraryScript");
        document.head.appendChild(libraryScript);
    }

    if (typeof window.ZeresLibrary !== "undefined") this.initialize();
    else libraryScript.addEventListener("load", () => { this.initialize(); });
    }
       
    stop() {
        PluginUtilities.showToast(this.getName() + " " + this.getVersion() + " has stopped. :( :(");
    };

    //  Initialize
    initialize() {
        this.initialized = true;
        PluginUtilities.showToast(this.getName() + " " + this.getVersion() + " has started. :D :D");
    }
}
```

I get an "Example could not be unloaded" error too.
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure whats wrong with it but here is an example of working code.

```
 /**
 * @name PLugin Name
 * @version 0.0.1
 * @description Example Description
 * @author Username and/or tag
 *  
 */



   module.exports = class name{
     
       load() { }
       start() {

//your code


}
stop(){
  
}
}
```

is the template i use, it works fine for me.

Here is an example of a small plugin i made that works just to try it out.

```
    /**
 * @name GifHider
 * @version 0.0.2
 * @description tired of looking at a gif? hide it!
 * @author Archer2305#7876
 *   
 */
//https://media.tenor.co/videos/af68e294135a577e8f4aa52a1f94f3e7/mp4


 module.exports = class Gifhider{
     
    load() { }
    start() {
        var b;
   var LOCK= false;
        BdApi.alert(BdApi.React.createElement("input", {
            style: {
              color: "white",   
              background:"#36393f"
            },
            className:"InpArg"
          }));
           
setInterval(function() {
  var inp= document.querySelector(".InpArg") 
          if(inp!=undefined||inp!=null&&LOCK==false){
            LOCK=true
           b= inp;
             console.log(b.value)
          } else{  
var count = 0;
if (document.getElementsByTagName("video").length>0){
do {
 if (document.getElementsByTagName("video")[count].src==b.value) {
//console.log("Gif blocked");  
document.getElementsByTagName("video")[count].style.display = 'none';
}
else {
//console.log("false");
}
 count++;
} while (count<document.getElementsByTagName("video").length)
}
          }
}, 1);

}
stop(){

}
}
```

Comment: Just an update , The thing wrong is your meta tags, it should be as /* @meta */ not // {meta}

Comment: Is there any documentation for BetterDiscord API?

Comment: The only documentation is on the github, its very poor however.

Comment: Ohh ok! They should 100% make a better documentation and a tutorial series.